# Как исправить ошибку после установки phpMyAdmin, в CentOS 7.x?

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, centos, установка

### Нужно установить `phpMyAdmin`

> Конфигурация:
>
> - WEB-Сервер: Apache
> - ОС: CentOS 7.x
> - Виртуальная машина: BitrixVM
> - Версия PHP: 7.1.23

---

### Порядок предпринятых действий:

1. Загружаю на сервер необходимый репозиторий:

   `$ sudo rpm -Uvh http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm`
2. Затем, обновляю списки доступных пакетов из нового репозитория:

   `$ sudo yum update`
3. Включаю поддержку новой версии PHP 7.1:

   `$ yum-config-manager --enable remi-php71`
4. Устанавливаю phpMyAdmin:

   `$ sudo yum install phpmyadmin`

### Предполагаемый результат:

Ожидаю получить доступ к `phpMyAdmin` по адресу: `http://ip_моего_сервера/phpmyadmin`

### Результат:

[image: Результат]

**Прошу поддержки и скорого решения вопроса**

Comment: Текстовый выхлоп лучше всё-таки в виде текста, а не картинки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю что вас сподвигло вообще взяться за Битрикс,  однако дело ваше. Что касается вопроса, Битрикс требует  mbstrig.func_overload = 2, тогда как библиотеки входящие в phpmyadmin требут значение 0. Что делать ?  Если в этой виртуалке битрикс крутится на апаче (а я почему то не сомневаюсь), попробуйте конфиге апача прописать следующее

`<Directory /var/www/path/to/dir>
php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 0
</Directory>`

Папка эта - папка к тому, где лежит phpmyadmin, это должно сработать.

Ну и конечно же дело вкуса, однако при надобности я бы пользовался MysqlWorkBench, например.